# Query for where method through three associations

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations

I have three models:

> Invitation.rb

```
belongs_to :department
```

> Department.rb

```
belongs_to :organisation
has_many :invitations
```

> Organisation.rb

```
has_many :departments
```

Organization table has `tag` field.

I need to write a query to search for Invitations, for the organization of which there is a `tag` field with the content *'First tag'*

Something like this:

```
Invitation.joins(:department).joins(:organisation).where(tag: 'First tag')
```

But I don't know how to build such a query.

Comment: Why the <sql> tag? (Are you trying to write an SQL query?)

Comment: @jarlh If prompted in pure SQL, I can use it.

Comment: **Try this** :- Invitation.joins(:department).joins(:organisation).where("organisations.tag =?", 'First tag')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Invitation.joins(department: :organisation).where(organisations: { tag: 'First tag' })
```

Why? Because to "reach" the organisations table from invitations you can use the relationship between the departments table.

```
Table.joins(...).joins(...)
```

Is "joining" twice the same table, what you need is to reference the relatinoship between departments and organisations. That you can do it as:

```
{ department: :organisation }
```

Passing that to join loads a JOIN clause in the receiver with `departments` and in `departments` with `organisations`.

Notice the where clause can be used as `{ organisations: { tag: ... } }` or `["organisations.tag = ?", ...]`, they can be used interchangeably. What you use is just a matter of preference yours or from your colleagues.

Comment: Exactly! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks to you! Added a bit of context.

Answer (score 1):

To do what you are trying to do without changing your models you should pass a hash to the joins method like so:

```
Invitation.joins(department: :organisation).where(organisations: { tag: 'First tag' })
```

This tells ActiveRecord to use the department association as defined on the Invitation model *and* the organisation association from the Department model

To make your life a bit easier you can add a `has_many through` association like this:

```
class Invitation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :department
  has_one :organisation, through: :department
end

class Department < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :organisation
  has_many :invitations, inverse_of: :department
end

class Organisation
  has_many :departments, inverse_of: :organisation
  has_many :invitations, through: :departments
end
```

Now you can use the invitations relation on Organisation as follows:

```
Invitation.joins(:organisation).where(tag: 'First tag')
```

To see the sql (e.g. in the console) you can use the #to_sql method:

```
Invitation.joins(:organisation).where(tag: 'First tag').to_sql
```

Finally, if you use a scope (and dont like the hash in the where method in which you have to specify the table) you can use a "scope" and merge as follows:

```
class Organisation
  class << self
    def just_tagged
      where(tag: 'First tag')
    end
  end
end
```

Now you can refer to the scope within your query using `merge`:

```
Invitation.joins(:organistion).merge(Organisation.just_tagged)
```